# Como executar mais de um comando no powershell?

Tags: powershell

Tenho o seguinte commando do AWS Cli que roda no PowerShell do Windows e faz download de uma pasta especifica dentro de um bucket S3:

```
 aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73 . --recursive
```

Porém tenho outras coleções de imagens para fazer download também, segue exemplo:

```
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73 . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73A . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73Ba . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73Bb . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73Ca . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73Cb . --recursive
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73D . --recursive
```

Não gostaria de executar uma a uma e sim todas em um ENTER só, como executo vários comandos um atrás do outro de uma vez no PowerShell?

Comment: Talvez, aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar um *array* e passá-lo ao comando a executar:

```
@("RF73", "RF73A", ...) | % { aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/$_ . --recursive }
```

Neste exemplo, criamos um *array* com o nome das imagens a descarregar e passamos cada elemento do *array*, através do [`|`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6), ao [operador de laço `%`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6).

Este operador vai executar o código entre os `{}` para cada elemento presente no *array* e refere-se ao valor usado na presente iteração através do `$_`.

Nota:

Se quiser simplesmente ter várias expressões na mesma linha, pode separar cada expressão com um `;`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73 . --recursive; aws s3 cp s3://rfcarga/RF73A . --recursive
```

Comment: Perfeito Omni, gostei demais da opção com array !

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti optimo. Se entendeu o conceito, pode agora melhorar a linha para se adaptar melhor ao seu caso (exemplo: ler os nomes dos ficheiros a descarregar de um ficheiro e passar o conteudo da mesma forma que eu mostro na resposta (`Get-Content 'caminho ficheiro' | % {...} `)